# Busy inodes/dentries after umount in self-written virtual fs

Tags: linux-kernel, vfs

I wrote a simple FS that should only statically contain one file named `hello`. This file should contain the string `Hello, world!`. I did this for educational purposes. While the fs is mounted it actually behaves like expected. I can read the file just fine.

However after unmounting I always get

```
VFS: Busy inodes after unmount of dummyfs. Self-destruct in 5 seconds.  Have a nice day...
```

If I called ls on the rootdir while the fs was mounted I get

```
BUG: Dentry         (ptrval){i=2,n=hello}  still in use (-1) [unmount of dummyfs dummyfs]
```

on top of that.

What does this mean in detail and how can I fix it?

The mount and kill_sb routines call mount_nodev and allocate space for a struct holding the 2 inodes this FS uses.

```c
static struct dentry *dummyfs_mount(struct file_system_type* fs_type, 
int flags, const char* dev_name, void* data)
{
    struct dentry *ret;

    ret = mount_nodev(fs_type, flags, data, dummyfs_fill_super);

    if (IS_ERR(ret)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "dummyfs_mount failed");
    }

    return ret;
}

static void dummyfs_kill_sb(struct super_block *sb) {
    kfree(sb->s_fs_info);
    kill_litter_super(sb);
}
```

The fill superblock method creates the 2 inodes and saves them in the struct allocated by mount:

```c
static int dummyfs_fill_super(struct super_block *sb, void *data, int flags)
{
    struct dummyfs_info *fsi;

    sb->s_magic = DUMMYFS_MAGIC;
    sb->s_op = &dummyfs_sops;

    fsi = kzalloc(sizeof(struct dummyfs_info), GFP_KERNEL);
    sb->s_fs_info = fsi;

    fsi->root = new_inode(sb);
    fsi->root->i_ino = 1;
    fsi->root->i_sb = sb;
    fsi->root->i_op = &dummyfs_iops;
    fsi->root->i_fop = &dummyfs_dops;
    fsi->root->i_atime = fsi->root->i_mtime = fsi->root->i_ctime = current_time(fsi->root);
    inode_init_owner(fsi->root, NULL, S_IFDIR);

    fsi->file = new_inode(sb);
    fsi->file->i_ino = 2;
    fsi->file->i_sb = sb;
    fsi->file->i_op = &dummyfs_iops;
    fsi->file->i_fop = &dummyfs_fops;
    fsi->file->i_atime = fsi->file->i_mtime = fsi->file->i_ctime = current_time(fsi->file);
    inode_init_owner(fsi->file, fsi->root, S_IFREG);

    sb->s_root = d_make_root(fsi->root);

    return 0;
}
```

The lookup method just adds the `fsi->file_inode` to the dentry if the parent is the root dir:

```c
if (parent_inode->i_ino == fsi->root->i_ino) {
    d_add(child_dentry, fsi->file);
}
```

And the iterate method just emits the dot files and the `hello` file when called:

```c
if (ctx->pos == 0) {
    dir_emit_dots(file, ctx);
    ret = 0;
}

if (ctx->pos == 2) {
    dir_emit(ctx, "hello", 5, file->f_inode->i_ino, DT_UNKNOWN);
    ++ctx->pos;
    ret = 0;
}
```

The read method just writes a static string using `copy_to_user`. The offsets are calculated correctly and on EOF the method just returns 0. However since the problems occur even when the read method was not called I think it is out-of-scope for this already too long question.

For actually running this I use user-mode linux from the git master (4.15+x commit `d48fcbd864a008802a90c58a9ceddd9436d11a49`). The userland is compiled from scratch and the init process is a derivative of Rich Felker's minimal init to which i added `mount` calls for `/proc`, `/sys` and `/` (remount).

My command line is `./linux ubda=../uml/image root=/dev/ubda`

Any pointers to more thorough documentation are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gdb watching the `dentry->d_lockref.count` I realized that the `kill_litter_super` call in umount was actually responsible for the dentry issues. Replacing it with `kill_anon_super` solved that problem.

The busy inode problem vanished too mostly except when i unmounted after immediately after mounting. Allocating the second inode lazily solved that problem too.